# Infinitely strong absorbing potential must reflect all incoming particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have heard that an infinitely strong absorbing potential must reflect all incoming particles. I am sure I have heard this in the context of single-particle quantum mechanics but I cannot find a reliable source explaining this. Where can I find a reliable source explaining, or preferably deriving this?

Comment: I would guess that's just the statement that the tunneling probability goes to zero.

Comment: if possible, would you please provide me a textbook source of this statement?

Answer (score 0):

In this [article](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.472003) it's explained the reflection and transmission properties of a CAP. You can derive easily that if the potential is infinitely strong, the transmission term goes to cero:

$$
|\mathscr{T}|^{2}=\exp \left(-\frac{a b}{n+1}\right) \xrightarrow{W(L) \to \infty} 0
$$

with:

$$
a=\frac{\eta W(L)}{E} \xrightarrow{\eta W(L) \to \infty} \infty
$$